# How to use Animated Gif in a delphi form

Tags: delphi, animation, delphi-7, gif, animated-gif

I think theres no native support to gif animated images.

How is the best way? any free component that allow that? I was thinking in using a TImage and a ImageList + Timer, but I need to export each frame of the gif to a separated bmp file.

Answer (score 57):

It's pretty simple in modern Delphi. It's all built in. Drop a `TImage` onto the form and load the animated GIF into the Picture property. Then, start the animation by means of the [`Animate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFImage.Animate) property:

```
(Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;
```

You can control the animation with [`AnimateLoop`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFImage.AnimateLoop) and [`AnimateSpeed`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFImage.AnimationSpeed). It should be pretty easy to guess how to switch the animation off again!

Now, since you are using Delphi 7, you don't have the `TGIFImage` component built-in. However, you can download the code from [Finn Tolderlund's](http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/) website (you want the latest version of `TGIFImage`). With this version of the component, the code above should work fine, although I personally have not used it since I ported from D6 to D2010 a few years back.

All these various `TGIFImage` codes are really just versions of the same component, originally written by [Anders Melander](http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/#status) and, in 2007, donated to Embarcadero for inclusion in Delphi.

Comment: Beware the shit-show called Jedi VCL which will prevent loading animated GIFs into a TImage if it's registered.

Comment: @WarrenP I wondered why this approach no longer works... How to disable it? I tried the following but couldn't find a solution. (1) I have already disabled the 'Register global design editors' option when installing JVCL. (2) The Project Jedi branch of the IDE options window doesn't have related settings. (3), I couldn't figure out which of the installed JEDI packages might contain this feature, see https://ibb.co/sQ6b1CV

Comment: Also disabled the 'JvGif for .gif' checkbox of the JVCL installer, let the installer rebuilt the packages, but issue still exits.

Comment: Update: **working solution**: Disabled the JvMM packages when installing JVCL. If you can't do that, comment out the following line from JvMMReg.pas: `RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TJvGIFImage), nil, '', TJvGraphicPropertyEditor);`

Answer (score 11):

***this is simply loading an animated gif and not making one***

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin

  ( Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage ).Animate := True;// gets it goin'

  ( Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage ).AnimationSpeed:= 500;// adjust your speed

  Form1.DoubleBuffered := True;// stops flickering

end;
```

***stackoverflow has helped me and so my little bit in return :)***

Comment: DoubleBuffered := True is usually a bad move

Comment: Excellent code my dear friend. Shows me that flicker doesn't happen at all when you use the above code in a form which has no other control except the TImage. +1 for a flicker free experience.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but it may be a good idea to stop it when the form is not in focus to save resources.

Answer (score 5):

Searched Google for 'Delphi Gif' Came up with this

http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/

now part of Delphi

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use JVCL, like me, you will likely run into trouble with [Davids answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573900/2306907), because JVCL registers `TJvGifImage` for GIF files which does not descent from `TGifImage` (see comments to [Davids answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573900/2306907)).

In this case the easiest solution seems to be loading the GIF file directly from resources:

```
//eg in FormCreate:
FAnimationGraphic := TGifImage.Create;
FAnimationGraphic.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'GIF_XYZ_ANIMATION');
ImageAnimation.Picture.Graphic := FAnimationGraphic;

(ImageAnimation.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;

//eg in FormDestroy:
//FAnimationGraphic must be freed! 
//ImageAnimation.Picture is not owner of the image
FreeAndNil(FAnimationGraphic);
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67771027) for `TGifImage.LoadFromResourceName`

Comment: Alternatively one can use [JVCLs TJvGIFAnimator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36638528/2306907).