# How to show animations on the mainform?

Tags: delphi

I want to show a animation resource on the mainform.  i.e., when the user is waiting for data handling, animation is started, so the user is of entertainment.

How to do this easily?

BTW: I'm using VCL. Thanks.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/9573572/960757.

Comment: Is this a VCL or FMX question? The answer will be different depending on which framework you use.

Comment: I'm using VCL, not FMX.

Comment: Please edit the question to that effect

Comment: Added the imformation, thanks David.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Google is your friend, you know... http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TAnimate

Comment: Which part of the task are you stuck on? Please [edit] your question to explain how far you've gotten.

Answer (score 0):

try to use gif image, it's easiest way
this link will help you  [Link](http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/)

Comment: Delphi comes with GIF support out of the box

Comment: That is, depending on which version of Delphi, which isn't in the question.

Answer (score 0):

VCL has a `TAnimate` component that can play AVI files/resources.