# Animated gif in Delphi XE 7 VCL

Tags: delphi

i tried the solution suggested here in delphi 2010 and XE7

[How to use Animated Gif in a delphi form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573572/how-to-use-animated-gif-in-a-delphi-form/9573900#9573900)

both of them raise exception with the following message

> "Exception class EInvalidCast with message 'Invalid class typecast'."

Comment: Please show your code. It should work in normal circumstances, so we need some relevant information from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the components. In Delphi 2010 Graphic class was changed to TJvGIFImage by JEDI VCL and on XE7 Graphic class was changed to TdxSmartImage by devExpress.after I removed the related packages from install packages the problem solved.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question you asked.

Comment: I'm confused, your question had no mention that you were using any of this.

Comment: @Jerry-Dodge I didn't think that components may cause this problem. In addition on d2010 only JEDI is installed and on XE7 only Devexpress. so i thought that something is wrong with the delphi.

Comment: @david-heffernan I don't know how to explain, as I understand JEDI changes TImage.Picture property from TGIFImage to TJvGIFImage. when delphi wants to compile this line `Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage` becuase the left and right side are in different type(the left side is TJvGiFImage and the right side is TGIFImage ) raise "Invalid class typecast" Exception.
here is the ticket about this problem on devexpress support center. [link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q562011)

Comment: Yes. It's exactly as I said in my answer. The question makes no mention of 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The code you refer to is:

```
(Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;
```

The error message indicates that the checked `as` cast fails. Which means that `Image1.Picture.Graphic` does not descend from `TGIFImage`. Whatever you put into the image control, it would appear not to be a GIF image.

I realise that this answer does not give you precise steps to a working program. However, I believe that the first step is to understand what the error message means. Once you understand that you know where to look for the solution.

Comment: You need to put a `TGIFImage` into the `TImage` before you can then cast the `Graphic` to a `TGIFImage`, eg: `gif := TGIFImage.Create; Image1.Picture.Assign(gif); ... (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;`  or `Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('image.gif'); (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;` Either way, make sure `GIFImg` is in your `uses` clause.

Comment: @Remy The doesn't compile without GIFImg in the uses clause

Comment: I stated as much in my last comment.

Comment: @Remy My point is that we already know that GIFImg is in the uses clause because we know that the code has compiled