# Loading Gif Picture From Resources

Tags: delphi

I want to load animated .Gif Picture into TImage From .Res File but TImage prepare LoadFromResourceName() function only for MyImage.Picture .Bitmap.
I Write a Simple Code as Follow

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
  MyImage:TImage;
begin
  MyImage:=TImage.Create(Self);
  MyImage.Parent:=Self;
  MyImage.AutoSize:=True;
  MyImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('H:\Component\Automation\Test\Animation\TL.Gif');
  MyImage.Top:=0;
  MyImage.Left:=0;
  MyImage.Visible:=True;
  MyImage.Transparent:=True;
 ( MyImage.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage ).Animate := True;
 ( MyImage.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage ).AnimationSpeed:= 100;
end;
```

It Work Properly. Now, what should I do when I want to load .Gif Picture from .Res File?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Include the `gifimg` unit in at least one `uses` clause in your program.
2. Link the image to your executable as a resource.
3. Load the resource into a `TResourceStream` object.
4. Create a `TGifImage` object and load the image into it by calling `LoadFromStream()`, passing the stream from step 3.
5. Assign the `TGifImage` object to the `TImage.Picture` property.

Comment: @TLama Thanks. Why not just edit the answer? Please feel free to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I tried to do that but it raise a run time error

Comment: @TLama Feel free to make edits in my grace period. I would welcome them happily. Thanks.

Comment: @Fayyaz Works fine for me. Guess something is wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I tried to do that but it raise a run time error it can not find the resource name I add this line to my code 'RS:=TResourceStream.Create(HInstance,'TL', RT_RCDATA);' but at run time I receive an error "Resource TL not found"  would you please write me a simple Example code?

Comment: Maybe you could try some debugging first. I think it would be more productive for me to teach you how to debug such a problem. That would be of more benefit to you in the long run. First of all then, you need a resource viewer to check what is actually being linked to your process. Either XNResourceEditor or ResourceHacker will do. Run one of those, load your executable, and check that your image is attached correctly, and has the right name and type. Clearly it isn't attached correctly given the error message, so let's find out what went wrong.

Comment: I Use XNResourceEditor and check out the Executable file. All of the resources are linked to Executable file correctly

Comment: Clearly that's not the case. Clearly there's no resource with type `RT_RCDATA` and name `TL`.

Comment: Thank you for your help I Find out what is wrong I should define TL 10 "TL.gif" in My .RC File. But now when I try to use RS as a Stream in Command 'MyImage.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(Rs);' it raise run time error "access violation" what is wrong here?

Comment: Create a `TGifImage`, and use `LoadFromStream` on that. Then do `MyImage.Picture.Graphic := GifImage`.

Comment: Good. I note that this is the first of your 7 questions for which you have accepted an answer. Perhaps you might review your other questions and see if there are answers to them that can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is about the missing `LoadFromResourceName()` procedure, use this class helper (add this unit) to add the missing procedure for `TGifImage`:

```
unit Mv.VCL.Helper.Imaging;

interface

uses
    VCL.Imaging.GifImg;

type
    TGifImageHelper = class helper for TGifImage
        procedure LoadFromResourceName(AInstance: HInst; const AName: string);
    end;


implementation

uses
    System.SysUtils,
    System.Classes,
    WinApi.Windows;     //RT_RCDATA


procedure TGifImageHelper.LoadFromResourceName(AInstance: HInst; const AName: string);
var
    ResStream: TResourceStream;
begin
    try
        ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(AInstance, AName, RT_RCDATA);
        try
            LoadFromStream(ResStream);
        finally
            ResStream.Free;
        end;
    except on E: Exception do
        begin
            E.Message := 'Error while loading GIF image from resource: ' + E.Message;
            raise;
        end;
    end;
end;

end.
```

This addresses points 3 and 4 from @Davids answer.