# how do i animate TJvGIFImage?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, jvcl

i have been using `TGIFImage` for while but i stuck with Some bugs with it so i decided to move  To `TJvGIFImage` and here how i load image

```
AGIF := TJvGIFImage.Create;
AGIF.LoadFromFile('what ever image');
AGIF.Transparent := true;
```

but there is no animate property inside `TJvGIFImage` like in `Tgifimage`

as eg .

```
 AGIF := TGIFImage .Create;
 AGIF.LoadFromFile('what ever image');
 AGIF.animate := true;
 AGIF.Transparent := true;
```

how do i set the animation for `TJvGIFImage` ?

Comment: Please try to check what the tags mean before randomly applying them. JCL means nothing like you think it does, so I'm removing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to show an animated gif with TJvGIFImage, you should use TJvGIFAnimator instead of TImage.
TJvGIFAnimator as an animate property as well as some other properties for animation.

```
procedure TForm2.LoadGif(const AFilename: string);
var
  aGif: TJvGIFImage;
begin
  aGif := TJvGIFImage.Create;
  try
    aGif.LoadFromFile(AFilename);
    JvGIFAnimator1.Image.Assign(aGif);
    JvGIFAnimator1.Animate := true;
  finally
    aGif.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -3):

Try the TJvGIFAnimator component?

Comment: TJvGIFAnimator  is not Tgraphic !

Comment: Please don't answer a question with another question.

Comment: @martin maybe not, but why not dig a bit to see what it is?

Comment: @RobKennedy Point taken.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Amen.