# Cannot play animated GIF in Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, animation, gif, playback

I download a animated GIF file from [image]. The following the instructions in [How to use Animated Gif in a delphi form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573572/how-to-use-animated-gif-in-a-delphi-form) to play it. But what I see is always a white block without any animation. Why?

Let me describe the process in details:

When I try to add the animated GIF, I see the following screen:

[image]

After clicking "OK" button, I will see below:

[image]

The whole project(Delphi 10.3) is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/jbsj86fgpq6qkpi/TestGIF.zip?dl=0

The related codeline is only below:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;
( Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage ).AnimationSpeed:= 500;
end;
```

More information:

1. I see Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg is added automatically after I set the picture to the GIF image.
2. I cannot see the first frame in the designer, what I can see is a white block.
3. I have tried other GIF images.For static images, they can be displayed properly. For animated GIF, when I load it, the Picture Editor will be able to show the first frame, but when I select "OK", the TImage will become a white block again.

Comment: It works for me in 10.3. I assume you also read the comments to the A you link to and have made sure you don't have the JVCL issue.

Comment: I try in 10.3 but also failed. I do not have JVCL installed.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, I try XE3, 10.3 and 10.2 on computers without any additional VCL installed. But all failed.

Comment: Which unit do you have in the `uses` to show the gifs? Obviously you load the image at design time. Do you see the first frame while in the designer? Have you tried with other .gif images?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I see Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg is added automatically after I set the picture to the GIF image. I cannot see the first frame in the designer, what I can see is a white block. I have tried other GIF images. For static images, they can be displayed properly. For animated GIF, when I load it, the Picture Editor will be able to show the first frame, but when I select "OK", the TImage will become a white block again.

Comment: Thanks, what if you try with a completely **new application**. New project, add `TImage` and then from properties, `Picture`, `...`, `Load...` and after selecting a gif file, finally OK. Then run.

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Also add a `TButton` and the `  (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;` to the button's `OnClick`

Comment: @TomBrunberg, Yes, I just do in that way. I have added more info to my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not before I downloaded the image you referred to, that I could reproduce the problem.

The reason, (at least the only way I could reproduce the "error"), is that the `TImage` at the default designer size is 105 x 105, in which case it shows a part (top-left) of the image. The image is 630 x 637, and the visible part shown in the `TImage` is the top-left white area, where the spinner never draws.

**The simple correction** is to set the `Proportional` property `True`

Note also, that the picture editor window does scale the image to fit in its viewport.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solve the problem perfectly.